# Is the Trial-Phase relaxing Test-enforcing and ToolingAPI to save APEX on Production Orgs?

Tags: apex, unit-test, tooling-api, trial

As a great surprise I have noticed today at the org of a new client (his Org is running in the Trial-phase) that APEX Tests seems not to be enforced and that I could modify and save APEX quickly using ToolingAPI.

So I thought that on production Org this is TRUE:

- can not use ToolingAPI to save/modify APEX
- MUST run all test EVERYTIME a single APEX is saved

Questions:

- Is the Trial-phase the reason why I actually can do both things on this org?
- if the Trial-phase is the reason: is there a way to get the relaxed way of trial-phase back somehow after the regular contract of our client is active and the trial-bar in the top is disappeard?
- is the difference of this behavior documented in detail somewhere?

Comment: Yes, as far as I am aware, while org is in trial phase you can still change apex classes in production using any tools without unit tests (aka in dev org). I can not find any documentation neither

Comment: this is odd. it should be documented and it should be available as an option ALWAYS.

Comment: found 2 things  -- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005267&language=en_US&type=1. Also basic description about what was(?) trial org can be found on web archive -- https://web.archive.org/web/20140608163743/https://www.salesforce.com/platform/force-trial-FAQ.jsp, page is deprecated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can not use ToolingAPI to save/modify APEX

True.

> MUST run all test EVERYTIME a single APEX is saved

False. For a few releases now, you've been able to specify RunSpecifiedTests during deployment; as long as all classes tested cover at least 75% each and all triggers at least 1% each, deployment can succeed. This allows you to deploy a single class that has a single unit test without running all tests (RAT).

> Is the Trial-phase the reason why I actually can do both things on this org?

Yes, it's the same as a Sandbox or Developer Edition org.

> if the Trial-phase is the reason: is there a way to get the relaxed way of trial-phase back somehow after the regular contract of our client is active and the trial-bar in the top is disappeard?

No, you have to go through the standard deployment process. Why? Because it protects your business from accidental changes that render your org unusable. Some of salesforce.com's largest clients do millions of dollars in business every day on Salesforce, and losing your org for even a day could result in catastrophic losses. I don't have an exact number for our org, but a back-of-an-envelope calculation suggests a bad deployment could easily cost us $10,000,000+ a day in revenue. Trial mode also has a number of other subtle differences, such as limited [emails-per-day](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220238&type=1), that would make it unsuitable for running a business.

> is the difference of this behavior documented in detail somewhere?

Not specifically, though a few articles, such as the one in the prior paragraph, do go in to limits regarding a feature when in trial mode as opposed to full production mode.